# Angular2: loop through a recently pushed array and push from another

Tags: arrays, angular, foreach

I have an array object

```
MainArray = {"Data":
             [{"Group": "GroupA"},{"Group": "GroupB"}]
}
```

then I loop through the array and created a new

```
let _newArray : any[] = [];
MainArray.Data.forEach(item => {
      _newArray.push({
              groupname : item.Group,
              columns: ["column1","column2","column3"]
            });
        //loop through _newArray.columns
        });
```

then I need to loop through the columns of new Array inside the Main Array loop

and push an array from another..

```
SecondArray = [{group: "GroupA", value: "firstfield", count: 14 },{group: "GroupA", field: "secondfield", count:23 },{group: "GroupB", field: "randomfield", count:1 }]
```

so the output should be

```
_newArray = [{
         groupname: "GroupA",
         columns: ["column1","column2","column3"]
         col1: [{"firstfield":14, "secondfield": 23 }]
         col2: "",
         col3: ""
         },{GroupB...}]
```

what I tried:

```
 Object.keys( _newArray[0].columns).forEach( function(value, key) {
                console.log(this._SecondArray[item.Group])
                // push  'col + index: [Second Array]'
                });
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can I loop inside a pushed array and push again eg. 'col + index: [Second Array]'

Answer (score 0):

In your SecondArray the first object is having a 'value' key. I assumed it as "field"

```
let MainArray = {
  "Data":
  [{ "Group": "GroupA" }, { "Group": "GroupB" }]
}

// First push
let _newArray = [];
MainArray.Data.forEach(item => {
  _newArray.push({
    'groupname': item.Group,
    'columns': ["column1", "column2", "column3"]
  })
})


let SecondArray = [{ group: "GroupA", field: "firstfield", count: 14 }, { group: "GroupA", field: "secondfield", count: 23 }, { group: "GroupB", field: "randomfield", count: 1 }];

// Second push
_newArray.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
  let i = 1;
  item.columns.forEach(cols => {
    console.log(cols)
    if (i == 1) {
      item["col" + i] = {}
      SecondArray.forEach(subItem => {
        console.log(subItem)
        if (subItem.group == item.groupname) {
          item["col" + i][subItem.field] = subItem.count
        }
      })
      i++
    } else {
      item["col" + i++] = ""
    }
  })
})



console.log(_newArray);
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response but col1, col2, col3 is dynamic I'm thinking of looping through the pushed columns to get these keys. so if there's "column4", there should be col4

Comment: You want to create the new Array first from the MainArray, 
And then modify newArray once the SecondArray is available. Am I right? @Yzak

Comment: yes thats correct thanks but should loop through columns to make col1 - col3 or whatever length columns be

Comment: One more query, should the matching secondarray contents always belong to col1? @Yzak

Comment: thats correct I'll have a different content for 2 and 3 but thats for future ref